# Find and replace in specific column only

Tags: replace, google-sheets, find, keyboard-shortcuts

In Google Sheets, I want to replace one value like "old_example" into "new_example" in only one specific column. How can I replace?

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find and replace for value in whole spreadsheets but I want to replace from only one specific column.

Comment: Since this "problem" can be resolved by using the standard, built-in features of Google Spreadsheets, I strongly suggest that you should delete your "Solved" edit. In addition, since your "solution" appeared shortly after you posted the original question, some may wonder whether your question is spam - and, of course, this would be something to be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and do:

[image: 0]

Comment: Apologies. Looks like we doubled up on the answer, but yours is clearly the better of the two.